# ERROR: Trying to get property id error in Laravel (non object)

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

can you please describe whats wrong with my code below. Their is an error when I click Update button and getting id of update Request. What I want to do is to update category name and tag with a post (post_tag i.e belongstoMany)
And it says "Trying to get property of non-object.

//class Post extends Model

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}

public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
}
```

// class Tag extends Model

```
    public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
}
```

// class Category extends Model

```
protected $table = 'categories';

public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

// PostController

```
public function edit($id)
{
    // find the post in the database and save as a var
    $post = Post::find($id);

    $categories = Category::with('posts')->get();
    $cats = array();
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $cats[$category->id] = $category->name;
    }

    $tags = Tag::with('posts')->get();
    $tags2 = array();
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $tags2[$tag->id] = $tag->name;
    }
    // return the view and pass in the var we previously created
    return view('backend.pages.posts.edit')->withPost($post)->withCategories($cats)->withTags($tags2);
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // Validate the data
    $post = Post::find($id);

    if ($request->input('slug') == $post->slug) {
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'title' => 'required|max:255',
            'category_id' => 'required|integer',
            'body'  => 'required'
        ));
    } else {
    $this->validate($request, array(
            'title' => 'required|max:255',
            'slug'  => 'required|alpha_dash|min:5|max:255|unique:posts,slug',
            'category_id' => 'required|integer',
            'body'  => 'required'
        ));
    }

    // Save the data to the database
    $post = Post::find($id)->first();

    $post->title = $request->input('title');
    $post->slug = $request->input('slug');
    $post->category_id = $request->input('category_id');
    $post->body = $request->input('body');

   
    if (isset($request->tags)) {
        $post->tags()->sync($request->tags);
    } else {
        $post->tags()->sync(array());
    }
    $post->save();
    notify()->success("The blog post was successfully updated!", 'Success');

     return redirect()->route('app.posts.show', $post->id);
    // return back();

}
```

//edit.blade.php file

// An error appears in select option finding an id which is a non-object

// A 2 line code below which is inside of form POST METHOD {{ route('app.posts.update', $post->id) }} //

```
<select class="form-control" name="category_id" class="form-control @error('category_id') is-invalid @enderror" required>
@foreach($categories as $key=>$category)
    <option value="{{ $category>id }}" @isset($post) {{ $post->category->id == $category->id ? 'selected' : '' }} @endisset>{{ $category->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

// Same error below tag name cannot get property

```
<select class="form-control select2-multi" id="tags" name="tags[]" multiple>
        @foreach($tags as $key=>$tag)
            <option value="{{ $tag }}" {{ old('tags[]', $post->tag)->contains($tag) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $tag->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

//End form

Comment: At what code line did you get the error? Can you comment that on your code?

Comment: When I try to update select category an error occurs on this code of code .
              <option value="{{ $category>id }}" @isset($post) {{ $post->category->id == $category->id ? 'selected' : '' }} @endisset>{{ $category->name}}</option>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. the `$categories` variable the you pass to the view is an array, with keys are category ids and values are category names. In your view, inside the loop, that `$category` variable is a string, but you try to access that as an object (`$category->id`) and get the error.

**SOLUTION 1:**

You can update your code like this:

```php
<select class="form-control" name="category_id" class="form-control @error('category_id') is-invalid @enderror" required>
@foreach($categories as $categoryId => $categoryName)
    <option value="{{ $categoryId }}" @isset($post) {{ $post->category->id == $categoryId ? 'selected' : '' }} @endisset>{{$categoryName}}</option>
@endforeach

<select class="form-control select2-multi" id="tags" name="tags[]" multiple>
    @foreach($tags as $tagId => $tagName)
        <option value="{{ $tagId }}" {{ old('tags[]', $post->tags)->contains($tagId) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $tagName }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

I see that in the controller action, you transform you categories and tags to arrays, which is not necessary. Just get those from the database and pass to the view.

```php
public function edit($id)
{
    // find the post in the database and save as a var
    $post = Post::find($id);

    $categories = Category::with('posts')->get();


    $tags = Tag::with('posts')->get();

    return view('backend.pages.posts.edit', [
        'post' => $post,
        'categories' => $categories,
        'tags' => $tags,
    ]);
    // Or you can even write: return view('backend.pages.posts.edit', compact('post', 'categories', 'tags'));
}
```

Then in your view:

```php
<select class="form-control" name="category_id" class="form-control @error('category_id') is-invalid @enderror" required>
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <option value="{{ $category->id }}" @isset($post) {{ $post->category->id == $category->id ? 'selected' : '' }} @endisset>{{$category->name}}</option>
@endforeach

<select class="form-control select2-multi" id="tags" name="tags[]" multiple>
    @foreach($tags as $tag)
        <option value="{{ $tag->id }}" {{ old('tags[]', $post->tags)->contains($tag->id) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $tag->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: When I click button page loaded and nothings happen ... I think its came from my POST method...any idea?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Do you mean submitting the form?

Comment: Yes exactly... A page continue to load but nothings happen.

Comment: You want to log some data inside the controller action to debug: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging#introduction

Comment: I tried to use log and it seems laravel log says tt is something happened  on channel which is on slack....i dont know what is slack is.

Comment: Pls comment or remove the `notify()` line. That's a different issue and you deal with that later.

Comment: Nothings happen when uncomment the notify() and it is not save from the database.

Comment: Thank you ... I got it on my slug validation error. Thanks for logging.!